# Why 'go get' use https even if ssh is configured?

Tags: git, go, ssh, bitbucket, go-modules

I have configured ssh properly and I can do git stuff with our private repo via ssh. But when I tested with `go get` or `go test` (for go modules) the cli is not using ssh but instead using https.

*.gitconfig*

```
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:7999"]
    insteadOf = https://bitbucket.company.com/scm
```

*~/.ssh/config*

```
Host bitbucket.company.com
 User git
 Port 7999
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

*testing if ssh works*

```
$ git ls-remote ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:7999/project/repo.git
ab86e12ab20775a308b7d0b003ba562263fbfa23        HEAD
ab86e12ab20775a308b7d0b003ba562263fbfa23        refs/heads/master
ab86e12ab20775a308b7d0b003ba562263fbfa23        refs/tags/v0.0.1
```

*testing go get*

```
$ go get -v bitbucket.company.com/project/repo
go get bitbucket.company.com/project/repo: unrecognized import path "bitbucket.company.com/project/repo": https fetch: Get "https://bitbucket.company.com/project/repo?go-get=1": dial tcp 10.68.204.3:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

*go version*

```
go version go1.14.1 windows/amd64
```

*go env*

```
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\sailhenz\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\sailhenz\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GONOPROXY=none
set GONOSUMDB=*.company.com
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\sailhenz\Documents\Development\Go
set GOPRIVATE=*.company.com
set GOPROXY=https://goproxy.io,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Users\sailhenz\Documents\Software\go
set GOSUMDB=off
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Users\sailhenz\Documents\Software\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=NUL
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\sail~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build227330694=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Any setup/configuration I missed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bitbucket.company.com/project/repo` does not match witch `https://bitbucket.company.com/scm`.

Comment: even matched the pattern but still no luck.

Comment: Hey, read this thread:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27344

Comment: I somehow managed to trace the issue and it seems that adding `.git` in the import path resolves it. Link of the thread here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27254 for anyone with the same issues.

Comment: @sailhenz Good catch. I have included that issue in my answer below, with some details about the problem caused by the lack of a `.git` in said import path.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[url "bitbucket.company.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://bitbucket.company.com/
```

That would transform any `https://bitbucket.company.com/` into `bitbucket.company.com:` which would then:

- be interpreted as SSH URL
- be decoded (through `~/.ssh/config`) as `ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:7999/...`

The key is to use `bitbucket.company.com` alone, which is the Host entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file, and means it will refer to the right private key file.

---

[subham sarkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5821408/subham-sarkar) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071929/why-go-get-use-https-even-if-ssh-is-configured/61072822#comment108047003_61071929) about [`golang/go` issue 27344](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27344)

The solution mentioned above does not seem to work with Go 1.13, and is in "backlog" with Go 1.14.

Check for testing if the same go get would work with Go 1.11.

---

The [OP sailhenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/692280/sailhenz) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071929/why-go-get-use-https-even-if-ssh-is-configured?noredirect=1#comment108054748_61071929) [issue 27254](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27254)

### `cmd/go`: custom import path private repos require special configuration

> adding .git in the import path resolves it

The ticket adds:

> The reason the `.git` solution works is that it helps guide the `go tool` with information about where the VCS for custom import paths `private.repo.net/user/package.git/...` resides (namely `(https|ssh)://private.repo.net/user/package.git`).
>
> Without this (i.e. with an import path like `private.repo.net/user/package/a`), the `go tool` first queries `https://private.repo.net/user/package/a?go-get=1` to work out (according to https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) where the VCS for that custom import path lives.

A `go get -x private.repo.net/user/package` is a good way to debug this.

Comment: I still have the same issue. `go get` somehow trying to connect thru https. ``` dial tcp 10.68.204.3:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: @sailhenz What version of Go are you using (see my edited answer)

Comment: I am using `go version go1.14.1 windows/amd64`. I also tried the solutions given in the thread and also tried to downgrade to 1.12.9 but still no luck. It's still trying to connect using https so I can't download any private repos. I will try with 1.11 and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: I have downgraded to `go version go1.11.13 windows/amd64` but `go get` still using https. ``` Fetching https://bitbucket.company.com/project/repo?go-get=1
https fetch: Get https://bitbucket.company.com/project/repo?go-get=1: dial tcp 10.68.204.3:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) ```. I'm going to put my `go env` in my original question.

Comment: @sailhenz OK, so another issue is the problem. Can you add your PATH as well?